# Enable boolean true on succesfull completion of form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

My use case is I have a wicked Wizard and its the registration model

- First user have to register his account am using devise
- A confirmation mail will be sent to the user's inbox.
- after successful confirmation user will be redirected to the registration page-1 followed by page-2 and page-3.
- I need to have a boolean to keep track of registration process.

so when user completes the first page successfully a boolean value will be made true.This is because user profile will not be visible until he/she fills in complete details,
any suggestion will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Ovefflow. Here we expect you to have a go at writing your app yourself first. Try all the bits that you know how to do. Then google all the bits you're unsure of, and then try doing what the google-results tell you. Then when you come across an error - google the error message and see if you can find a solution... then finally anything that's left, you come here and write up a description of the error, and include the relevant snippets of code you're written, and ask for help solving that particular bug. Then we can begin to help you :)

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for the warm welcome. I am relatively new to ROR,I am  not ending up with anything remotely relevant to what am searching at this particular scenario, It would be amazing if you point me in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far? :)

Comment: Hey!! I am using the Enum to update the status I don't know whether its the right approach. By default the scope will be 0 => inactive and after completing the profile I want to make it 1 => active, Is this approach is solid?

Comment: It's hard to debug a verbal description... can you you edit your question and actually add the relevant snippets of code you've got so far? I can then take a look and suggest what can be changed to make it do what you'd like. Show us what you tried even if it's not working or if even if you're not sure it's the right approach - it'll give us a better idea of what you're trying to do so that we can help you build on that or suggest alternatives. :)